# remix - npm run dev stuck on built

Tags: node.js, npm, build, remix.run

When I run npm run dev on a remix project (default template used), I am noticing that my build gets stuck on the step of built.
Version of remix used,

```
 "@remix-run/node": "^2.5.1",
 "@remix-run/react": "^2.5.1",
 "@remix-run/serve": "^2.5.1",
```

Commands I tried,

```
npm run dev

> dev
> remix dev --manual


   remix dev

 info  building...
 info  built (578ms)
```

I have also tried using npx after removing my **build** and **cache** folders, tried changing the **port** thinking this may be an issue but I still see the same problem.

```
npx remix dev --manual  --port 5001

   remix dev

 info  building...
 info  built (539ms)
```

Would also like to point out that the package.json script was a default one which was working earlier.

Default scripts from `remix`,

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "remix build",
    "dev": "remix dev --manual",
    "lint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --cache --cache-location ./node_modules/.cache/eslint .",
    "start": "remix-serve ./build/index.js",
  },
```

It recently stopped connecting to prisma and after I terminated the build and tried running the same default command, remix fails to build and start the project. Can anyone provide some pointers? thanks.

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Your question led me to realize that I wasn't connecting to prisma anymore but I still haven't gotten it to build again.

Comment: let me know where you land. I was able to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time I realized that I was trying to call the prisma functions directly. Instead Remix have a concept of loaders to load anything from the backend.

Here is what I have done to resolve this,

imports are important,

```
import { json } from "@remix-run/node";
import { useLoaderData } from "@remix-run/react";
```

First need to create a function called loader,

```
export async function loader() {
  return json(await db.note.findMany());
}
```

then calling the following in whichever component I needed,

```
const notes = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
```

This allowed me to successfully call my `helper db.server` file to retrieve data.